# Need help positioning an element based on it's width (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a stepper UI, and going "forward" things seem to work nicely. Going backward from beyond "Step 3", the positioning seems to be off. I think I'm targeting the wrong element, but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated. Codepen: https://codepen.io/abenjamin/pen/aepMEW?editors=1111

HTML

```
<div class="stepper-ui">
  <figure class="bar"><div class="line"></div></figure>
  <ul class="progress-stepper">
    <li class="step active">Overview</li><li class="step">Shipping</li><li class="step">Payments</li><li class="step">Returns</li><li class="step">Contacts</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
<button id="next" onclick="regress()">Back step</button>
<button id="next" onclick="progress()">Next step</button>
```

JS

```
function regress(){

  // Look for the active step
  let activeStep = document.querySelector('.active');

  // Look for the previous step
  let previousStep = activeStep.previousSibling;

  // Get the width of the element   
  stepWidth = stepWidth - previousStep.clientWidth - 32;

  // Step backwards
  stepPlace--;

  // Count the steps
  let stepCount = document.getElementsByClassName('step').length;
  // Calculate the new width of the meter

  meterWidth = ((100/stepCount)*stepPlace);
  // Update the styling to show the new meter width
  progressMeter.style.cssText = "width:"+meterWidth+"%;"
  // Slide the text to the left using the width of the step element
  steps.style.cssText = "transform:translateX("+(stepWidth)+"px);"
  // Remove the .active class from the active step
  activeStep.classList.remove('active');
  // Add the .active class to the newly active step
  previousStep.classList.add('active');
  console.log(stepWidth);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the minus sign on the `translate` property

```
function regress(){

  // Look for the active step
  let activeStep = document.querySelector('.active');

  // Look for the previous step
  let previousStep = activeStep.previousSibling;

  // Get the width of the element   
  stepWidth = stepWidth - previousStep.clientWidth - 32;

  // Step backwards
  stepPlace--;

  // Count the steps
  let stepCount = document.getElementsByClassName('step').length;
  // Calculate the new width of the meter

  meterWidth = ((100/stepCount)*stepPlace);
  // Update the styling to show the new meter width
  progressMeter.style.cssText = "width:"+meterWidth+"%;"
  // Slide the text to the left using the width of the step element
  steps.style.cssText = "transform:translateX(-"+(stepWidth)+"px);" // <-- here
  // Remove the .active class from the active step
  activeStep.classList.remove('active');
  // Add the .active class to the newly active step
  previousStep.classList.add('active');
  console.log(stepWidth);
};
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks.